# Override and replace default JS component

Tags: magento2, overrides, uicomponent, requirejs

I want to replace default component `Magento_Ui/js/grid/columns/actions` with my own component that extends default one.

This is my `./view/adminhtml/requirejs-config.js`:

```
var config = {
    map: {
        '*': {
            'Magento_Ui/js/grid/columns/actions': 'Vendor_Module/js/grid/columns/actions'
        }
    }
};
```

This is my `./view/adminhtml/web/js/grid/columns/actions.js`:

```
define([
    "jquery",
    "Magento_Ui/js/grid/columns/actions"
], function ($, Component) {
    "use strict"

    debugger
    return Component
})
```

My custom module is loaded but original (default) **"Magento_Ui/js/grid/columns/actions"** is undefined (cause I have replaced it in `requirejs-config.js` I suppose).

How can I extend original component in this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `requirejs-config.js`

```
var config = {
    map: {
        '*': {
            'Magento_Ui/js/grid/columns/actions': 'Vendor_Module/js/grid/columns/actions',
            uiGridColumnsActions: 'Magento_Ui/js/grid/columns/actions'
        }
    }
};
```

and in your file reference not the original path but the mapping name:

```
define([
    "jquery",
    "uiGridColumnsActions"
], function ($, Component) {
    "use strict";

    return Component;
});
```